# Charging 2 cell LiPo battery with MCP73213

Tags: battery-charging, microchip, lipo

I'm using an MCP73213 to charge a two-cell 7.4v LiPo battery using this circuit, when I tried charging the battery it was fine when I did this steps:

1. Connect 12V power source
2. Connect LiPo Battery

But when I had the LiPo 1000 mAh Battery connected and then I plugged the 12V Power Source which is a wall adapter the MCP73213 started burning and it's no good right now, I'd like some help unraveling this mistery since I don't know why this happened.

I noticed the MCP73213 is heating a lot but this IC shouldn't be burned since it has thermal regulation which reduces the charging speed whenever the temperature goes beyond 85°C (Datasheet section 5.9)

[image: MCP73213 charging schematic lipo]

Wall adapter 
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00KZ2ZQE8/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KZ2ZQE8)

Battery
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0072AEHIC/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o07_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0072AEHIC)

Comment: Where is your Cout?  Cin?  Section 3.2 of datasheet:  Connect to the positive terminal of the battery. Bypass to VSS  with a minimum of 1 μF to ensure loop stability when the battery is disconnected.   Section 5.3.3 The  MCP73213  detects  the  battery  presence  with charging  of  the  output  capacitor...

Comment: I just edited the image, I have a Cout but not a Cin, do you think having no Cin might've burned the IC?

Comment: No Cin would not do that.  I probably do not know more than you.  There are some guys on here that are very good at these types of things.

Comment: What is the capacity (mAh) of your battery, and what is the 12V power source?

Comment: 1000 mAh and a wall adapter, I edited the question